# manipulating location.href of frame with PDF plugin in IE9

Tags: javascript, pdf, internet-explorer-9

I'm experiencing rather strange behaviour in IE9 when loading a PDF in a frame with Javascript. The document will load once, but any subsequent invocation will result in `SCRIPT65535: Invalid calling object`.

I'm constructing my URL from Javascript and loading through `top.framename.location.href='file1.pdf'`. If you start with a PDF in the frame, it will fire the error upon the first invocation of the script.

So, it appears you are no longer allowed to modify the `location.href` property of a frame in which the Adobe Reader plugin (version 10) is loaded. The same code with HTML documents works fine.

Does anybody know why this behaviour was changed, and if there is a workaround other than using IE8 emulation with `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8">`?

I'm also not looking for workarounds that completely avoid the Javascript. There are numerous options, like constructing the link elsewhere and loading it with a `target` attribute, but I'd really like to do this with Javascript.

If you want to test/reproduce, you can use:

```
<frameset cols="150,*">
<frame src="toc.html"/>
<frame src="about:blank" name="otherframe"/>
</frameset>
```

and in toc.html:

```
<a onclick="javascript:top.otherframe.location.href='1.pdf'">pdf1</a><br/>
<a onclick="javascript:top.otherframe.location.href='2.pdf'">pdf2</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/internet-explorer-9-jquery-and-divx

> When I go to IE9 developer tools (F12) and under Script tab, click on
>   Start debugging button, I get details about the error: SCRIPT65535:
>   Invalid calling object  script block (2), line 72 character 4
>
> When you look at the script line 72, this line is highlighted:
>   appendChildOriginal(element);
>
> Then I go to IE9, Manage add-ons, under Toolbars and Extensions, look
>   for Divx, LLC and disable Divx Plus Web Player HTML5 and DivX HiQ and
>   restart IE9 Browser.
>
> The error is gone and my web application work perfectly.

Comment: That was the only reference I found. Unfortunately the Divx plugin isn't installed, so it can't be causing it. Also, it happens with plain javascript. I've given up, and decided it must be a side effect of new security measures (which are useless as long as the attacker can force IE8 or IE7 behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.

In IE9, the frame object is replaced by some PDF object that doesn't contain the `location` property. So the second time you cannot update the frame url with `location`.

You can solve this by using window.open()

```
window.open('1.pdf', 'otherframe');
```